# Satellite L755 Black Screen flicker

Tags: windows-7, display, graphics-card, toshiba-laptop

Basic problem is that my laptop has been doing this screen flicker from what I can tell. I can be in the middle of something and then the screen will quickly go black for 1 to 2 seconds. What could this signal? A slow graphics card failure?

Comment: Or is it possible that the driver does need an update, currently i've put it back to factory default to resolve a previous issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rather sounds like the backlight is tuning off temporarily, which would mean, that the screen becomes completely dark, not only very dark grey. Check this without any ambient light. It might happen more often if you move the lid and if it is off, you should still be able to see the picture on the screen but very dim and with very low contrast. Lighting the screen with a flashlight from the side (with a low angle) will help to see a picture if it is still there. It might also happen more/less often, if you change the brightness setting.

If you can confirm this, this is either the backlight itself or a worn out inverter or cable and you should contact Toshiba as the laptop is probably still in its warranty period.

If not, this might be the graphics chip, but problems with the chip usually show different symptoms and are also likely to be seen with an attached external monitor. Intel graphics are also rather unproblematic regarding chip faults or driver issues. So I am quite sure, the backlight is the problem.

Comment: i'm not entirely certain if it is the backlight, for that brief moment that it went black i couldnt see anything on screen, i'm suspecting i might have loosened a cable when i last opened it up to get rid of dust on the inside. I'm due to take it apart again and replace the thermal heat so i'll have a look if i did knock anything out. Failing that i will contact toshiba and get them to see to it, its only 9 months old and well under the warranty. Thanks for the tip :)